# jackson limit cascade serialization

Tags: json, jackson

How to configure jackson to limit cascade serialization.

I have a class File and one of its attribute is parentFile.

```
@Entity
class File{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected File parent;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    protected Set<File> childFiles;
}
```

So when I serialize a File, jackson serialize the parent and so on, till it reaches the root file.
I 'd like to serialize only the file and its parent and that's it, is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using this annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties. This way I get the full parent File serialized but without its own parent.

```
@Entity
class File{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("parent")
    protected File parent;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    protected Set<File> childFiles;
}
```